# root login after ldap install?

Tags: login, root, ldap

I have set up `ldap` on my local network following the Ubuntu Manual.

For some reason (after ldap setup, not before), it seems to have made a root entity in my `ldap` tree, which now allows for the availability of root logins. Why? I thought Ubuntu's whole deal was avoiding having a actual root login?

I found it very surprising when I went to work and tried to `ssh` into my home machine with the root account and supplying it a password worked.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just create an LDAP account called root? Does it really have actual root permissions?

Comment: I did not create a root ldap account, and yes it does have root perms...

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that you really talking about root check the uid of the account.
After login invoke `id`. The output should be:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

*root* is just a name, the special rights belong to the uid **0**.

If you have a 2nd account *root* with a "normal" uid different from 0 delete this bogus account.

If your *root* account has the uid 0 ensure that the sshd configuration deny root login.
Ensure that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` include the setting:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Note: Ubuntu has surely a root account. The difference to other distribution is, that normally no password is assigned to this account.

Comment: I have never had a root account working on ubuntu with out it causing massive issues.... I dont understand why all the sudden its now active and with a password....
I have removed the ability to log into it via ssh... 
the UID is 0 . 
I normally use sudo to become root,  Now i feel like reinstalling linux because I dont know what else this has done...